# Having a Dropdown over a Dropdown menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a site here (http://beta.ohsinsider.com/) which has a dropdown in the search bar (http://screencast.com/t/cBGeEYGroZ), but when the person hovers over it the menu extends over yet another menu and is causing a ton of UI issues with the users. Is there some way to make the menu underneath not take precendence if I am on the search dropdown? Having two menus close to each other is turning into a task..!

Comment: Have you used the `z-index` CSS attribute?

Comment: in what browser do you have the problem? Because in firefox and ie 8 I can view it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS z-index + absolute positioning of the search drop-down maybe ?